# Algebraic approach to Local Analytic Complex Geometry

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, ringed-spaces

I'm attending a second course in Complex Analysis from a geometrical point of view.

In the final part of the course we have discussed about germs of complex analytic sets and their algebraic properties (Link with germs of holomorphic functions, Weierstrass Division Theorems, Nullstellensatz for complex analytic sets...)

I feel as there could be a less geometric and more algebraic approach to deal with this objects, using commutative algebra and/or schemes theory and/or locally ringed spaces theory:

Someone can give me some references to look how could algebra be a powerful instrument in local complex analytic geometry?

Comment: Scheme theory is useless in local analytic geometry.

Comment: Are you interested to analytic spaces?